# Analog LTC3106 issue

Tags: battery-charging, solar-cell, charger, lipo, buck-boost

I'm trying to use LTC3106 to provide 3.3V for my SAMD21. The goal is to use the sun when it is available (and recharge the battery with the excess) and use the battery when there is no sun.
Here is my schematic with modifications :
[image: Schematic]

My main issue is that I did not get 3.3V in Vout.
There is some strange behavior that I did not understood :

- When I measure my solar panel before connection, got 3.5V - 4V (depend of the light) and when I plugged it in Vin and the GND, got 0.8V between these two pins
- When my battery is charged, got about 4V between Vstore and Gnd, and 4.5V in Vout (instead of 3.3V)

Why Vout is not always on 3.3V ?
What is EN ?

Comment: No load?  ENable…

Comment: Why did you disable MPP connecting it to Vcc? I suggest use a resistor to set the MPP voltage and test with some load.

Comment: Load is plugging something on Vout ? (Like a LED ?)  Because for this test there was nocomponent on Vout.